# How to 2 Input Parameter in Java?

Tags: java, input

I have a text file of inputs to be plugged into a java program but I'm not sure how to make it go through the input text file and loop to get each pair of words from the line to compare the length. I'm trying to make a program that compares the length of each character and outputs the longer one as a practice while learning java.

in.txt

5

Apple Carrot

Melon Banana

Strawberry Grapes

Tomato Pear

Kiwi Mango

What I did for now is use the Scanner package for reading the input.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class MaxLength
{
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int cases = scan.nextInt();
      String first = scan.next();
      String second = scan.next();

      for (int i =0; i < cases; i++)
          check(first, second);

      sc.close();
  }
  public static void check(String first, String second)
  {
      if (first.length() > second.length())
          System.out.println(first);
      else
          System.out.println(second);
  }
}
```

It seem that it is not looping through all of the pairs and only gets the 1st string pair. I'm new to java and I have not seen any example to this.

Comment: `for (int i =0; i < cases; i++);`  here remove semicolon

Comment: Hi @PandeyAmit cool it runs but it seem to be only getting the first line of the input ? I'm not sure how to loop it to all the lines

Comment: Edited the loop too, but it reprints the answer to the first line only?

Comment: Where the `check()` function is defined?

Comment: I've updated the code to show the check function

Comment: Do you mean to print largest line among all five line in the `in.txt` ?

Comment: No I want to compare each string from each line (ie. Apple and carrot; melon and banana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not looping, I mean your input reading is not in the loop so you should change your code to:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class temp
{
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int cases = scan.nextInt();
      String first = "", second = "";

      for (int i =0; i < cases; i++) {
          first = scan.next();
          second = scan.next();
          check(first, second);
      }

      scan.close();
  }
  public static void check(String first, String second)
  {
      if (first.length() > second.length())
          System.out.println(first);
      else
          System.out.println(second);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I've tried placing the scan next inside, and it produced an error of variable first might not have been initialized? in the check function

Comment: It didn't compile or just it was a warning?

Comment: @Funky you can initialize the variables to some empty string before reading though.

Comment: It shows error: variable first might not have been initialized. But I already initialized it outside the loop like what you've suggested?

Comment: @Funky I edited the answer and it's working as expected. :)

Comment: `@Funky happy coding :)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consecutively scan your input, you need to put that `scan.next()` into a loop.
You also need to know, that `scan.nextInt()` just gets an Integer value. That means, if you want to get all values, you should use scan.next(). Also use a while loop with `while(scan.hasNext())` to see if a next row exists instead of a for loop

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    first = scan.next();
    second = scan.next();
    check(first, second);
}
```

Comment: The question constraints suggest that the input format is known and there are `cases` pair of string separated by space in a line so the for approach is good enough!

Comment: I've tried this and it worked but I need to constrain it to the number of cases that was stated on the first line

Answer (score 0):

Use code below like this.

```
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int cases = scan.nextInt();
            String first = "";
            String second = "";
            for (int i =0; i < cases; i++) {
                first = scan.next();
                second = scan.next();
                check(first, second);
            }

            scan.close();
```

Comment: It says I cannot declare a variable inside the loop

Comment: I have changed the code declared `first` and `second` variable outside loop and initialized it with empty string. by the way declaring variable inside the loop is not a problem in java until unless you are not re-declaring variable again in the same scope